# Jolt: How do I split the json value and capitalize it in the output json?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to transform this:

```
{
    "key": "MyNamespace.myName", 
    "value": true
}
```

to

```
{
  "data": {
    "header": {
      "namespace": "MyNamespace",
      "name": "SetMyName",
      "messageId": "UUIDString"
    },
    "payload": {
      "myName": true
    }
  }
}
```

A couple of questions here. First, I'm not sure how to split the json value of `key`, `MyNamespace.myName`, into two parts, which will be assigned as values of the keys `namespace` and `name`, respectively, as part of the `shift` operation.

Second, I need to transform the case of `myName` by capitalizing the first letter of the name, so it becomes `MyName`, before appending it to `Set`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Answered here, note it takes multiple steps.

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/688